# How to restore existing class and skins directory after reinstall xcart 5.3?

Tags: x-cart

I'm testing the xcart platform, but the problem is after I reinstall xcart and copy & paste my on-working backup directories back to the correct directory (class and skins). There is no content show on the customer's page.

I did cache it several times but same result with no content shown.

Any idea to solve this issue?

Comment: Did you restore the MySQL database too? It should match the files on your server (i.e. a database from one X-Cart installation won't work on other X-Cart installation unless the installations have the same source files).

Comment: I fixed it by copy my module through phpStrom. Thanks.